# how to insert double and string values to MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

this is my code to insert something to mongoDB

```
List<DBObject> write=new ArrayList<DBObject>();   //write is a list of objects
```

//i am using loop to get each object from list.

```
DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("product_name", item.getName()).
                            append("product_url", item.getUrl()).
                            append("product_img", item.getImage()).
                            append("product_price", item.getPrice()).
                            append("time",item.getTime()).
                            append("category", item.getCategory());
write.add(doc);
```

// t = db.getCollection(table);
    t.insert(write);

when i tried this with price as string value no error.. i want to change price to double value for that i changed my price to double and then i changed my code as

```
getdouble("product_price", item.getPrice());  //used this instead of .append
```

but then error and telling me to change doc to double.. but i cant change doc to double because other values are string and it will again show error..

Please tell me how to insert double with other string values to mongoDB

I am a new to MongoDB

Comment: You can't replace append with getDouble, append is for setting mongo object value, getDouble(String attrName, double defaultValue) if for getting the double value within attribute attrName with a default value in case of attrName is missing.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mixed types in one column you have to check for type before (this code is for **reading** a record):

```java
if(obj.get("product_price") instanceof String) {
    item.setPrice(Double.parseDouble((String)obj.get("product_price")));
} else {
    item.setPrice(obj.getDouble("product_price"));
}
```

Writing a new record should be straightforward, just use append the double value :

```java
DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("product_name", item.getName()).
                            append("product_url", item.getUrl()).
                            append("product_img", item.getImage()).
                            append("product_price", item.getPrice()).
                            append("time",item.getTime()).
                            append("category", item.getCategory());
write.add(doc);
```

Of course Item must have getPrice() declared as :

```
public double getPrice() {return price;}
```

Comment: while i setprice to object i use double always.. so how can i insert a double value to mongoDB

Comment: String price="30";
item.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(price));
using this to set price ..

Comment: As simple as this : DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject().append("product_price", item.getPrice()). item.getPrice() have to return a double.